# Reading a HTTPResponse to a tar file

Tags: python, io, stream, response, tar

I'm using [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#get_archive) to read files and folders from a container. As I use the method `get_archive()` I want to save it to a tar file, since it returns a tuple of a raw tar data stream, and the stats:

```
>>> import docker
>>> cli = docker.Client()
>>> ctnr = cli.create_container('busybox', 'true')
>>> stream, stat = cli.get_archive(ctnr, '/bin/sh')
>>> print(stat)
{u'linkTarget': u'', u'mode': 493, u'mtime': u'2015-09-16T12:34:23-07:00', u'name': u'sh', u'size': 962860}
```

The `stream` object is a `requests.packages.urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`. I want to read the content on the stream and write it to a tar file. How can I accomplish this? I tried a bunch of things, but it only worked with files, but not with directories.

Answer (score 2):

The stream is raw tar data, so first, you need to write it to a file:

```
ctnr = cli.create_container('busybox', 'true')
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    (data, _) = ctnr.get_archive('/bin/sh')
    for chunck in data.stream():
        tmp.write(chunck)
```

Then, open this file as a tar archive and extract it.

```
tmp.seek(0)
with tarfile.open(mode='r', fileobj=tmp) as tar:
    tar.extractall()
    tar.close()
```

Note that I used the high-level api.